# Why does telegram.Bot.getUpdates() long polling returns immediately?

Tags: python, long-polling, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

According to [telegram api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), the `getUpdates` function receives incoming updates using long polling ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)).
From wiki:

> If the server does not have any information available for the client
>   when the poll is received, instead of sending an empty response, the
>   server holds the request open and waits for response information to
>   become available. Once it does have new information, the server
>   immediately sends an HTTP/S response to the client, completing the
>   open HTTP/S Request.

Then, why does the function `getUpdates()` returns immediately, even though the `timeout` parameter is set?

The function call:
`bot.getUpdates(offset=lastUpdateID, timeout=120)`

There are no new updates and the offset=lastUpdateID is the last update.

I'm using library [python telegram bot library](https://github.com/leandrotoledo/python-telegram-bot)

Comment: I had a similar experience, but my mistake was that I overlooked the sentence "Defaults to 0, i.e. usual short polling." in the description of the "timeout" parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was I asked for `offset=lastUpdateID x`, and I should have asked for `offset=lastUpdateID x + 1`